In LaTeX beamer, can you reveal points on a slide with an animation, without resetting the animation?
So I would like to reveal some points on a slide where an animation plays, but whenever a new point is revealed, the animation resets. Is there any way to stop the animation from resetting?
Here's an MWE to play around with:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example of Animation with Revealing Points}


  \animategraphics[loop,autoplay,width=\textwidth]{10}{./data/animation-}{0}{10} 

  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Point 1
    \item<2-> Point 2
    \item<3-> Point 3
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


Do you want to reveal the points during or after the animation?

Hi! Preferably during the animation.

Is there a fixed correspondence between the animation step and the reveal of a certain point?

No, there is no relation. Sorry for the lack of information. I didn't realize these things would be important, but now that you mention them they make sense.

Too bad! Otherwise I would have suggested a \multiinclude approach.

There recently was a question a question how to keep the sound running on page changes and somebody wrote a new viewer (can't remember if it was for pdf or svg files). Maybe something like this could be used to keep a video of the animation running. If I find the question again, I'll give you a link.

Ah, here it is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/716659/36296 I have absolutely no idea if a similar approach would work for video.

Thank you so much! This is already helpful. I will check it out.

beamer overlays are physical PDF pages and a self-contained, independent animate animation will be embedded on each of them.
While scrolling through the overlays, these animation "incarnations" need to communicate with each other to prevent the animation flow from being reset. If a PDF page opens, the current animation needs to know the frame number at which the previous animation stopped. Then, it can continue playing from that frame.
This communication can be implemented with pkg animate's JavaScript interface and with an invisible, non-interactive PDF widget. To enable the JS interface, each animation needs to be given a unique label based on the page number. The widget performs the necessary actions on the page open and close events:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \let\myPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\putBeforeAnim#1{%
  % invisible, noninteractive widget with page close and open actions
  \myPdfAnnot{1ex}{1ex}{0pt}{%
    /Subtype/Widget/F 2/FT/Btn/Ff 65537/T (animctrl-\thepage)%
    /AA <<%
      % action on page-close: save current animation frame number
      /PC << /S/JavaScript /JS (try{ var #1CurFrame  =anim["#1_\thepage"].frameNum; } catch(e){}) >>
      % action on page-open: set current animation frame number to the saved one
      /PO << /S/JavaScript /JS (try{ if(#1CurFrame) anim["#1_\thepage"].frameNum=#1CurFrame; } catch(e){}) >>
    >>%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Example of Animation with Revealing Points}

  \putBeforeAnim{myanim}%
  \animategraphics[label=myanim_\thepage,loop,autoplay,width=0.3\textwidth]{1}{example-image-a4-numbered}{0}{11}%

  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Point 1
    \item<2-> Point 2
    \item<3-> Point 3
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


What a brilliant solution!

Insider knowledge :)

It's great to have an insider around! :)

This is great, thanks a lot! I have a small issue though: whenever I reveal the next point, the animation jumps back to the first image for a split second, before continuing where it left off. Is there anything I can do about it?

That's a problem which is hard to circumvent, because on each page open event, the animation is initialised and displays its default poster frame before setting the animation frame from the previously open animation.

Ah I see. Is it maybe possible to manually change the default poster frame? E.g. to an empty image?

Yes, add poster=none to the options :)

Awesome! This makes it less confusing especially at higher frame-rates.
